# How can I set a label from the code behind of a page?

Tags: asp.net

Upon page load I want to set the content of a label on a page. I'm moving from MVC and is used to set this in the View return function of that controller. But how can I do this with ASP.NET Forms, if I wanted to fetch the weather at the users location I would want to write "Hello user, it is sunny outside" in the code behind and send it to the page - but how?

Comment: just add a asp:Label control on the page, give it a ID like ID="myLabel" and runat="Server" and then in your code behind set the label text as `myLabel.Text = "Hello user, it is sunny outside";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the aspx, just add a label with id and runat server like this:

```
<asp:Label id="myLabel" runat="server" />
```

And in the code behind you can set the text like this:

```
myLabel.Text = "SomeText";
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a asp:Label control on the page, give it a ID like ID="myLabel" and runat="Server" and then in your code behind set the label text as myLabel.Text = "Hello user, it is sunny outside";